# Velocity.js and calc() CSS function

Tags: javascript, css, velocity, velocity.js, css-calc

I'm trying to animate an element's width using velocity and the calc() function.

```
$("#menuContainer").velocity({width: "calc(100% + -260px)"}, 500);
```

this animates the element's width to 0.

Does [.velocity](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) not support the css function [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)? or am do i overlooking a basic syntax error?

Comment: Why do plus a neg, instead of just minus?

Comment: You are missing the `)` in calc?

Comment: Change to `"calc(100% + -260px)"`

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith - a mistake when typing out the problem on here - the error remains in the code with this amendment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use

```
$("#menuContainer").velocity({width: '-=260px'}, 500);
```

For **50%** width, you can use:

```
var menu=$("#menuContainer");      
menu.velocity({width:menu.width()/2}, 500);
```

Comment: Great, what if I need 50%?